# Inconsistent Jackson deserialization of String as LocalDateTime

Tags: jackson, deserialization, jooq

I am deserializing a nested collection in JOOQ via Jackson.
The error I am encountering is like this,

`` Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Cannot construct instance of `java.time.LocalDateTime` (no Creators, like default constructor, exist): no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value ('2020-12-18T11:29:03.290833') at [Source: (String)"{"wrapped_ts" : "2020-12-18T11:29:03.290833"}"; line: 1, column: 21] (through reference chain: blah.blah.WrappedTimestamp["wrapped_ts"]) ``

This is inconsistent with behavior earlier in the deserialization process. A MRE would be,

```
=== Function using JOOQ ===
.select(
    TOP.ts,
    field(
        select(
            jsonArrayAgg(
                jsonObject(
                    LOWER.lowerTs
                )
            )
        )
        .from(LOWER).join(TOP).on(TOP.ID.eq(LOWER.TOP_ID))
    ).`as`("lowerLevels"),
    field(
        select(
            jsonObject(
                WRAPPED.FIRST,
                WRAPPED.SECOND
            )
        )
        .from(WRAPPED)
        .where(TOP.ID.eq(WRAPPED.TOP_ID))
    ).`as`("wrapped")
.from(TOP)
.where(condition)
.fetchInto(TopLevel::class.java)

=== Underlying data classes ===
@JsonNaming(PropertyNamingStrategy.SnakeCaseStrategy::class)
data class TopLevel(
    ts: LocalDateTime?,
    lowerLevels: List<LowerLevel> = emptyList(),
    wrapped: WrappedTimestamp?
)

@JsonNaming(PropertyNamingStrategy.SnakeCaseStrategy::class)
data class LowerLevel(
    lowerTs: LocalDateTime?,
)

@JsonNaming(PropertyNamingStrategy.SnakeCaseStrategy::class)
data class WrappedTimestamp(
    first: LocalDateTime?,
    second: LocalDateTime?,
) {
    constructor() : this(
        null
}
```

There are three different levels of timestamps. `ts` and `lowerTs` both deserialize fine, `wrappedTs` throws the error above. If it's unclear, my Jackson ObjectMapper does have the JavaTimeModule registered.

In the course of debugging I have created new deserialization targets at the level of WrappedTimestamp that function with no issue. I have also commented out the `wrapped` section of the select in JOOQ and it also works.

What could be accounting for this inconsistent behavior?